# App Store crashes not being reported in Crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have setup Crashlytics according to what the documentation says, like so:

```
// In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class], [Twitter class]]];

// In Info.plist
<key>Fabric</key>
<dict>
    <key>APIKey</key>
    <string>myAPIKey</string>
    <key>Kits</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>KitName</key>
            <string>Crashlytics</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
            <dict>
                <key>consumerKey</key>
                <string>myConsumerKey</string>
                <key>consumerSecret</key>
                <string>myConsumerSecret</string>
            </dict>
            <key>KitName</key>
            <string>Twitter</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

However, I seem to only get a subset of the crashes reported to Crashlytics. When I go through the steps for forcing a crash (call `[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash];` and run the app without the debugger attached), the bug gets recorded. On our App Store build, however, I am aware of crashes happening that I can not see in Crashlytics. Is Crashlytics not able to catch all crashes for some reason? Except for OOM related crashes, I can not find any evidence of this in the documentation.

**Answers to what I assume the first comments will ask about:**

- My Debug Information Format is set to DWARF with dSYM File.
- Bitcode is disabled.
- The App Store build is definitely set to Release mode and not Debug mode.
- The Fabric dashboard says that no dSYMs are missing.

Comment: I am seeing a similar issue too.

Answer (score 0):

I was finding this issue too, and there was no indication of missing DSYM's in Crashlytics. However, I used their recommended technique to upload my DSYM, and immediately saw the crashes. I include my script here:

```
#!/bin/bash
# From https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#bitcode-download

# Upload a DSYM for your app to Fabric/Crashlytics if it's missing.
# Usage uploadDsymFabric <Dsym>.zip

# For a production release, I had to first download the DSYM from iTunes Connect.

# I got this from the Info.plist
API_KEY="<snip>"

/Applications/Fabric.app/Contents/MacOS/upload-symbols -a $API_KEY -p ios $1
```

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on where `[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash];` is in the code. If the crash is happening before `Crashlytics` is initialised then the crash won't be reported.

Another possibility is that the crash is happening in the app extension and then `Crashlytics` needs to be setup separately for all app extensions.